# What packages add support for different VPN types to Network Manager?

Tags: package-management, network-manager, vpn

What VPN types does Network Manager support, and what packages do I specifically need to install to allow the support of those VPN protocols?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? 12.04 LTS for example supports PPTP and OpenVPN out of the box but additional libraries can be installed to expand the kinds of VPNs network-manager can support. A popular plugin is vpnc for example which is used to connect to a corporate Cisco based VPN sever.

Comment: As an FYI, this is a ***generic question*** because I want it to apply to all currently supported releases (and probably future ones).  Not just any one release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, all the NetworkManager vpn plugins are in packages which match `network-manager-*`.  For example:

- `network-manager-pptp` - Adds the PPTP VPN plugin.  Included on a default install.
- `network-manager-openvpn` - Adds the OpenVPN VPN plugin.
- `network-manager-iodine` - Adds support for Iodine-based VPNs.  *(available in Quantal (12.10) and later)*
- `network-manager-vpnc` - Adds the VPNC VPN plugin.
- `network-manager-openconnect` - Adds the OpenConnect VPN plugin.
- `network-manager-strongswan` - Provides a VPN plugin for strongSwan, providing easy access to IKEv2 IPSec VPN's.

These packages should also pull in any required dependencies for each VPN plugin.  (`network-manger-openvpn` will install the `openvpn` libraries and dependencies, for example)

Comment: network-manager-iodine not found... is the name correct?

Comment: This looks like a pretty complete list.  I will caution you on the use of `network-manager-*` though, as not *all* the packages matching that pattern are actually VPN plugins, some add KDE support and things, and aren't actually VPN plugins.  But you got most of the main VPN plugins here.  :)

Comment: @Dee he's correct the package does exist, but it exists in Quantal and later.  I've marked that accordingly in the answer.